# What are the supported Connection String properties for MemSQL?

Tags: singlestore

[This page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html) describes the supported connection string properties for MySql Connector / .Net.

Which of these options are officially supported when connecting to MemSQL?

I suspect that options like `SharedMemoryName` and `BlobAsUTF8IncludePattern` are not. However, I couldn't find any official documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found some of the links which can help you identify your answer in the latest version of Singlestore 7.8 (on premises). However, i saw few special options in singlestore connector/.Net [official documentation](https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.8/en/developer-resources/connect-with-application-development-tools/connect-with-net-and-net-core.html?query=Blob+.net&page=1&namespace=db&version=latest).

Link related to .Net/C# Connection for concurrent multi insert [official documentation](https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.8/en/developer-resources/concurrent-multi-insert-examples/c-----net-core.html).

Go thru the above links from SingleStore's official documentation for more .Net connection related information.